# Error while reconnecting Intuit on java

Tags: java, intuit-partner-platform

I am working on intuit integration on my application. Now I am stuck on reconnecting process of it. While working on reconnecting, I am getting following exception:

```
 Message: Token Refresh Window Out of Bounds Caused By: null
```

Actually, While testing i used the keys which are not expired. It that the reason I am getting this exception?

I am working on java and my java code is:

```
public void renewQBOAccessToken(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        LOGGER.info("Inside renewQBOAccessToken method.");
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        Intuit intuit;
        try {
            intuit = IntuitLocalServiceUtil.getIntuit(PortalUtils.getCompanyId(req), PortalUtils.getOrganisationId(req));
            LOGGER.info("Values before ::::::::::::::::");
            IAPlatformClient client = new IAPlatformClient();
            client.reConnect(PropsUtil.get(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_KEY),
                    PropsUtil.get(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_CONSUMER_SECRET), intuit.getOauthToken(), intuit.getOauthTokenSecret());
            getAccessToken(req, resp);

            LOGGER.info(">>>>>>>>>>>> values after reconnect: ");
            LOGGER.info("accesstoken: +" + session.getAttribute(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_KEY));
            LOGGER.info("access token secret:" + session.getAttribute(CommonConstants.INTUIT_QB_OAUTH_ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET));
        } catch (PortalException | SystemException e1) {
            LOGGER.error(e1.getClass().getName() + " Exception while reconnecting  #renewQBOAccessToken Class: "
                    + e1.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Message: " + e1.getMessage() + " Caused By: " + e1.getCause());
        } catch (ConnectionException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getClass().getName() + " ConnectionException while reconnecting  #renewQBOAccessToken Class: "
                    + e.getClass().getSimpleName() + " Message: " + e.getMessage() + " Caused By: " + e.getCause());
        }
    }
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Yes. The token is not within 30 days of expiring.

See https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0053_auth_auth/oauth_management_api for responses.

Comment: Ok, Thanks, How can i verify those things? Can we create some keys whose expiration date lies on window and test properly?